# How to store and search efficiently huge MySQL lottery database

Tags: php, mysql

More than 1 million tickets each week. Users select 6 numbers between 1 and 49. ALL numbers(tickets) will be kept indefinitely. Each week winners will have to be selected.

In one table I have all users with ID number and Unique email. In tickets table I have Unique ticket ID, foreign key that references user ID, selected numbers field and timestamp. In some cases, one user can have more than one ticket in a given week.

1. What's the most efficient way to store this kind of data? More specifically, type of data to store numbers, keeping in mind that there will be a large number of entries and it also needs to be searched now and then.
2. With the data structure you propose, what's an efficient way to select all users in current week that picked 4 winning numbers, 5.. and 6.

I saw an idea about storing it as binary so 3, 6 would be 001001... Given that I consider myself an average programmer, that seemed genius to me. Easy to search and seems like few bytes to store (although I don't know how MySql stores its data exactly).
Is there a better way? The only disadvantage I see to that method is that it's not easily read by humans.

Update: link to binary idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931286/2374034

Comment: not buying ticket in the lottery, hope its not a real one

Comment: I've written an algorithm for next week's results. Interested?

Comment: You do understand that if you want 49 different options, you would need a 64bit number to be *able* to store it right? Because people can store anything between 0 and 2^49(!!) which is a HUGE number.

Comment: It's gonna cost ya! ;-)

Comment: @Tularis 49 bits needed... Nth bit selected represents number of ball. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1931286/2374034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the six values individually, you need a `TINYINT` per number, so a total of six 1-byte columns. This is your best choice.

You can save one extra bit of overhead per column by declaring columns as NOT NULL.

Other options are not as compact:

- Though you don't really need 8 bits per number, if the range of the numbers is 1-49. You only need 6 bits per number (store 0-48 in six bits).

  So you could store six number 1-49 in 36 bits. An `INT UNSIGNED` is 32 bits, so it's too small But a `BIGINT` can store 64 bits. There's no INT type in between 32 and 64 bits.

  To store the six numbers in a single `BIGINT`, shift each number by 6 bits and bitwise-OR them together.

  ```
  INT = (A-1) | ((B-1)<<6) | ((C-1)<<12) | ((D-1)<<18) | ((E-1)<<24) | ((F-1)<<30)
  ```

  The result won't be human-readable, but at least it's compact.
- To use `SET` to store a bitfield of six choices in the range 1-49, you'd need at least 49 bits (one bit per possible number chosen), so you'd need at least 7 bytes anyway. MySQL's `SET` stores in 1, 2, 4, or 8 byte increments, depending on the number of distinct `SET` elements. This one would require the 8 byte size.
- MySQL also has a `BIT` data type, and you can declare a `BIT(36)` column. But this data type uses space in 4-byte increments, so you'd end up using 64 bits per ticket anyway.

Ultimately, you're talking about TicketID + UserID + 6xTINYINT per ticket sold, so probably 16 bytes per row. There's some overhead, though. I just tested inserting 1048576 rows into a table with this definition. It takes about 40MB to store.

So you can count on needing about 40MB * 52 weeks = 2058MB per year. But these days, you can hardly buy a hard drive less than 500GB, so I think you'll be fine. By the time you fill up an average drive, it'll be time to upgrade to quantum computers anyway. :-)

---

Re your comment:

Yes, you can define an index on the date and make searches very efficient. Defining the right indexes must be determined by the queries you need to run.

Or you could define the table using [PARTITION BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) and use the date (or week) as the partitioning key. Be careful with partitioning, though, it's not always a panacea. You should read about its [limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html) carefully.

---

> How would you extract all the tickets that got 4 out of the 6 numbers right?

In MySQL, a boolean condition yields either a 1 or a 0, which you can then use in arithmetic.

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
WHERE (A=?) + (B=?) + (C=?) + (D=?) + (E=?) + (F=?) >= 4
```

This is bound to cause a table-scan, but you're going to suffer that no matter what solution you use for storing the data.

Comment: I am very tempted to use the SET datatype as it's easy to read and (at least in my head) the select statement to find the winners seems straightforward. Regarding space usage, a few gigs are certainly not a problem but what about search efficiency? Since I only need to search in the entries inserted in the last week, will it matter much if I search between date1 and date1+7days if I have 1 million or 10 million entries? I'm thinking(hoping) that MySQL can easily "cut" entries between date1 and date2 and then search through that.

Comment: Sorry to be a nag but it seems I wasn't so clear on my #2 question. Although I'll go with binary or SET datatype I'm still curious how a select query would look when using 6 TINYINT columns. How would you extract all the tickets that got 4 out of the 6 numbers right?

Comment: If the select winners query is frequent, you are justified in storing (caching) wins in a wins table that can be accessed by index.

Comment: @TomHaws, yes I agree that denormalization can be a legitimate optimization.

Answer (score 1):

1. Integer storage is efficient.  A TINYINT UNSIGNED column uses one byte and can store integers from 1 to 255.  I am assuming that it's important to keep pick numbers in their correct order, and that there are always 6 of them.  Therefore I suggest you use 6 TINYINT UNSIGNED columns for the numbers.  That would probably be better than binary.
2. I suggest a week table and a win table with week.id, week.name, win.id, win.week_id, win.user_id, win.match_count.

Comment: Always 6 numbers, that is right but order is unimportant. Thought about keeping order but couldn't find one reason why that would matter in this particular case. Why wouldn't SET datatype be appropriate? Regarding question #2 I meant the actual SELECT statement to search for the users that got 4,5 or 6 numbers right, sorry for being unclear.